# For Each loop element not declared

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I need to use VB within the framework of SSRS. I am trying to beautify some XPaths in order to make them more presentable to a human user of the report.
I haven't gone very far and I hit the first problem.

```
Module VBModule
    Public Function BeautifyXpath(ByVal s As String) As String
        Dim strBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder(s)
        If s.Contains("[") Then
            strBuilder.Replace("[%s]", "")
            strBuilder.Replace("@", "")
            Dim tokens = strBuilder.ToString().Split("/")
            For Each token In tokens
                Console.WriteLine(token)
            Next
            Return strBuilder.ToString()
        Else : Return s
        End If
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(BeautifyXpath("/priorities/priority[%s]/@patternName"))
    End Sub
End Module
```

I get the following error from the compiler:

> (8,24) : error VBNC30451: 'token' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Turn Option Strict On... Then your Dim tokens will bark, give it a type. For example: Dim token As String()... Then in your loop it knows that its a string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare token in your `For Each` statement.

```
For Each token As String In tokens
    Console.WriteLine(token)
Next
```

Or

```
Dim token As String()
For Each token In tokens
    Console.WriteLine(token)
Next
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) for more information.

Comment: You can also do it where its declared before the loop, where it should be done.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of this but didn't write it... I edited my answer. I'm confused. Does Dim token As String()... with or without () ?

Comment: If you look he is splitting the string into an array, so his dim statement would look like: `Dim token As String()`. Then in the loop you do not have to say what type...